# What would be a relatively simple way to prove modular congruence?

Tags: soft-question, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am pretty new to modular algebra. I know what $a \equiv b \pmod m$ means. I can prove simple congruences, for example the following:
$$
100 \equiv 43 \pmod {19}
$$
What I would do is apply a theorem which states that $ a \equiv b \pmod m \Longleftrightarrow m \mid a - b$, so:
$$
19 \mid 100 - 43 \\
19 \mid 57
$$
And this is true of course, since $19 \times 3 = 57$. Thus the congruence is true.

**The real question is**: What would be an efficient way to prove the following congruence?

$$
3456789 \equiv -9876543 \pmod {100}
$$

Of course I could apply the same method as with the first one, but it's a lot harder when it comes to large numbers...

Comment: It's not true; it's easy to check congruences modulo $100$ as $a\equiv b$ iff $a-b$ ends in $00$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown all right, I probably should have added that I am looking for general solutions. It's good to know that this method works with modulo $100$, so thanks for your comment! But I was looking for general methods. Also, as I said, I am looking for a method other than having to subtract the two numbers (which is tedious to do by hand)

Comment: $$a\equiv b\pmod n\iff n\mid a-b\iff \gcd(n,a-b)=n$$ Now, finding the gcd of two numbers is relatively efficient, thanks to [Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Then again, I guess this is still equivalent to checking whether $n\mid a-b$ which is not that much of a problem, you only need to check whether $\frac{a-b}n$ is an integer or not.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I haven't learned about this algorithm of Euclid as of yet. Essentially, what I am looking for is a way to simplify the congruence so that it's easier to be dealt with. I know there are ways to do this, but I don't know or understand them.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have worked out what I was looking for in the meantime. So our congruence was:
$$ 3456789 \equiv -9876543 \pmod {100} $$

What I could do here is look for a number which is divisible by $100$ (so the number $\pmod {100}$ is $0$). For example, let's use $3456700$. Then obviously:
$$ 3456700 \equiv 0 \pmod{100} $$
And since if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod {m}$ means that $a \pm c \equiv b \pm d \pmod {m}$ stands, I can simply subtract $3456700$ from $3456789$. Also, I have to subtract $0$ from $-9876543$, but it doesn't do anything. Then:
$$ 89 \equiv -9876543 \pmod {100} $$
Now I'll repeat the procedure but with the other side. This time, I'm saying:
$$ 0 \equiv -9876500 \pmod {100} $$ 
And thus:
$$ 89 \equiv -43 \pmod {100} $$
There, I have simplified my expression to two digit numbers. Now it's really easy to finish:
$$
100 \mid 89 - -43 \\
100 \mid 132
$$

This is obviously false, so the congruence is false.